# Start and End Tags for MJPEG?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, jpeg, mjpeg

I am trying to display the MJPEG stream in an iOS application. For this I need to refresh the imageView with the new image as soon as receive one. Would need to separate the images in the stream.
Are there some definitive start and end tags/bytes for individual images to separate them out?
Or any particular MJPEG parser for iOS?

I faced some issues while going with the following approach
[How to identify contents of a byte[] is a jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg)

Answer (score 3):

The Motion JPEG format is extremely simple. Every frame is stored as a JPEG image, and the data for all the images is concatenated into a single stream.

You can detect the start of a JPEG image by searching for the byte pair `FF D8` (the Start of Image tag), and the end by searching for `FF D9` (the End of Image tag). In a well-formed Motion JPEG stream, the end of each image should be immediately followed by the beginning of the next, so you may not need to check for the EOI tag.