# Java get image extension from byte array

Tags: java, image, tomcat

I have the below code for saving an image from a byte array.

I am able to save the image successfully using the below code.

Currently I am saving image with ".png" format but I want to get the image extension from byte array and save image with this extension.

Here is my code

```
public boolean SaveImage(String imageCode) throws Exception {
    boolean status = false;
    Connection dbConn = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    try {
        String base64Image = imageCode.split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);

        Properties propFile = LoadProp.getProperties();
        String filepath = propFile.getProperty(Constants.filepath);
        File file = new File(filepath + "xyz.png");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            fos.write(imageBytes);
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (callableStatement != null) {
            callableStatement.close();
        }
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

I am using Java and Tomcat 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify contents of a byte\[\] is a jpeg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg)

Comment: To extend on that: there's a whole list of magic numbers that indicate the file type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are many solutions. Very simple for example:

```
String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
```

Or you can use third-party libraries. Like [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/):

```
String contentType = new Tika().detect(imageBytes);
```

Comment: this is working only for png images for jpg images also it is giving as png extension

Answer (score 0):

Would you use the prefix header `data:image/png;base64` of the base64 image data?

From the RFC, the "data" url definition:

```
### Form : `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`
### Syntax:
`dataurl   := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
mediatype:= [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
data       := *urlchar
parameter  := attribute "=" value`
```

Samples:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAw......
```

Then you can get the extension with gif.

Comment: There is nothing in the question that tells us that the bytes are Base64 encoded and using a `data:` URL.