# Python .JPEG Recognition

Tags: python, jpeg

I was trying to write a program that would grab the ascii or binary behind a .jpeg and find for example the "JFIFHH" to verify thats its really a JPEG
the simple script i wrote was

```
    test = open('test.jpeg', 'rb')

data = test.read()
print(data)

if 'JFIFHH' in data :
    print('FOUND')

elif 'JFIFHH' not in data :     
  print('not found')
```

It always prints not found even if its there.
so i found out it wasn't the binary it printed but something else, so how can i make this work???

Comment: are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: are you sure of your pattern? `JFIF` is probably found but not sure of the `HH` part

Comment: also can you link to your jpeg file? that would help...

Comment: (doing my best here :))

Comment: also this is the wrong way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the proper pattern to look for in the first place. I checked a JPEG file and it contained `JFIF` but not `JFIFHH`...

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg) states you should look for `FF D8` start & `FF D9` end byte sequences, like this (Python 2/3 compatible code):

```
with open("test.jpeg","rb") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    if contents.startswith(b"\xff\xd8") and contents.endswith(b"\xff\xd9"):
        print("it's a jpeg")
```