# Getting ''Missing SOI marker.' from JpegDecoderr

Tags: c#, jpeg, imagesharp

I'm running into issues opening a jpg file. Here is the code I started with:

```
var image = await Image.LoadAsync("sample.jpg")
```

This produced the exception:

```
An exception of type 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.UnknownImageFormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Image cannot be loaded. Available decoders:
 - PNG : PngDecoder
 - GIF : GifDecoder
 - BMP : BmpDecoder
 - TGA : TgaDecoder
 - JPEG : JpegDecoder
```

To determine why the file wasn't recognized as jpeg, I used the following code:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("sample.jpg"))
{
   var jpegDecoder = new JpegDecoder();

   jpegDecoder.Decode(Configuration.Default, stream);
}
```

That gave me the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.InvalidImageContentException' occurred in SixLabors.ImageSharp.dll
Missing SOI marker.
```

I'm inclined to believe that the image involved has an issue, but I'm able to view it in windows photo viewer and in Google Chrome. How do I determine what is wrong with the file?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @user9938, I was able to determine that this is a RIFF or WEBPV8 file:

[image: Hex viewer]

Is there a riff plugin for ImageSharp by any chance?

Comment: The following may be helpful: http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ImageSharp folks have been toiling away at WebP support.

This issue does a great job of describing where the progress is at:

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/121

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if **Image.Load(imageStream)** called with a fileStream but Position is not set to zero you can also get decoder not found kind of errors...

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/164#issuecomment-291784371

Comment: test working, simple solution